Title: Unable to Build Anchor Project with SBF Tools: Issues with sbf-solana, bpfel-unknown-none, and Docker Compatibility
Description:
Hello everyone,
We’ve been struggling for hours trying to build an Anchor project on Solana. Despite numerous attempts, nothing seems to work, either locally or using Docker. Below are the complete details of the issues we’re facing:
Project Setup
Anchor CLI Version: v0.30.1
Anchor.toml:
toml
Copier le code
[build]
target = "bpfel-unknown-none"  # Also tested with "sbf-solana"
Cargo.toml:
Dependencies have been updated and adjusted, but no major conflicts were found.
Issues Encountered


Locally
Main Error:
When running anchor build, we see the following error:

go
Copier le code
error: no such subcommand: +solana
The SBF tools (v1.35) are installed, and we have tried defining the bpfel-unknown-none target in rustc.
Missing Targets:
Despite adding the targets with rustup target add, the following fail:
sbf-solana
bpfel-unknown-none
bpfel-unknown-unknown
Rust Versions Tested:
Locally, we’ve tested:
rustc 1.65.0-dev (pre-installed with the SBF Tools).
Nightly versions from 2022-07-12, 2023-07-12, and even the latest like 1.85.0-nightly.
However, dependencies like borsh and constant_time_eq require incompatible Rust versions.
2. With Docker
Docker Images Tested:
projectserum/build:v0.27.0
projectserum/build:v0.24.2
Custom images based on these versions, where we manually tried to add targets and nightly toolchains.
Problems Observed:
The bpfel-unknown-none target is unavailable in the installed nightly versions:
rust
Copier le code
error: component 'rust-std' for target 'bpfel-unknown-none' is unavailable for download
Both cargo build-bpf and cargo build-sbf fail with metadata errors or missing targets.
Attempted to manually install nightly and add targets in Docker using:
dockerfile
Copier le code
RUN rustup install nightly
RUN rustup target add bpfel-unknown-none --toolchain nightly
But these consistently fail with "toolchain not supported" errors.
Steps We’ve Tried
Rust Versions:
Tested both nightly and stable versions, including specific nightly versions like 2022-07-12, 2023-07-12, and the latest (1.85.0-nightly).
SBF Tools:
Installed manually using:
bash
Copier le code
curl -sSfL https://github.com/solana-labs/bpf-tools/releases/download/v1.35/solana-sbf-tools-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2 | tar -xjf - -C /usr/local
Verified that the SBF tools are in the PATH.
Docker:
Used both pre-configured images (projectserum/build) and custom-built ones.
Tried to manually add missing targets using rustup target add.
Anchor and Cargo:
Updated dependencies with cargo update.
Adjusted targets in Anchor.toml and Cargo.toml.
Current Observations
sbf-solana and bpfel-unknown-none targets fail, even in Docker with pre-configured environments.
Anchor’s +solana directive seems incompatible with the installed Rust version.
No Docker image seems to successfully build the project, even with added tools and nightly versions.
Questions
Is there a specific combination of Anchor, Solana, and Rust versions that reliably works with SBF tools?
Why are the required targets (bpfel-unknown-none, sbf-solana) missing or unavailable, even in nightly builds or Docker?
Does anyone have a working Docker image for building Anchor projects with SBF tools?
Has anyone encountered and resolved these issues? Any guidance would be much appreciated!
Useful Links
Anchor Discord: https://discord.gg/anchor-lang
Solana Stack Exchange: https://solana.stackexchange.com
GitHub Issues for Anchor: https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/issues
Does this cover all the details you’d like to share? Let me know if there’s anything else to add!

what version of solana are you running. The SBF tooling comes with that, if not installed, run the installation script sh -c "$(curl -sSfL https://release.anza.xyz/v2.1.5/install)"
